# Newlines in a TextView using a Spannable

Tags: android, html, textview, spanned

I have got the following issue. I have a `String` which I want to display in a `TextView`. Because the `String` can be HTML formatted I am using a `Spanned` like so:

```
TextView tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Description);
Spanned myDescription = Html.fromHtml(myDescriptionOriginal, null, null);
tv.setText(myDescription, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The "problem" I now have is that when the myDescriptionOriginal is not HTML formatted, the `fromHtml(...)` removes all newlines (and presumably also things like tabs).

Is there a general solution (perhaps as part of the `Spanned/Spannable/Html` classes, with which I am not too familiar) that solves this problem or is this something I have to write myself (I could for instance check if the myDescriptionOriginal contains HTML tags and if it doesn't I don't use the `fromHtml`)